# Arduino Nano and 0.96 i2c oled screen not working

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, display

[image: My wiring]When I try to scan the i2c address it stays stuck on "i2c Address Scanner" which is the first line of the code.
My screen is connected with VCC-5V, GND-GND, SCL- 4.7K resistor->A5, SDA- 4.7K resistor->A4.
Nothing displays on screen, and I even tried without the resistors. I also tried with some 10K resistors and same result.

> Here in the picture you can see how I connected the screen to the nano. SDA-A4, SCL-A5, VCC-5V, GND-GND.

Comment: Did you put the resistors in line?  Or as pull-ups?   Show how you wired that.  It sounds like you did it wrong.

Comment: Take A look in the picture I hope it helps, I'm a noob

Comment: A 4 kOhm resistor in series is too big. Such resistors are normally used as pullup resistors, so connection from SDA/SCL to Vcc. Resistors in series are in I2C only used to limit current, when having different voltage levels (lower values must be used). Also your solding seems not clean enough. You have tons of burned flux there and the solder points look like they might not give you good contact.

Comment: that is a really horrible soldering job ... i would not bother to do any troubleshooting until the board is cleaned up and the soldering is properly done

Comment: Yeah those resistors are wrong.  They should go from the pin to Vcc.  Not in line with the signal.

Comment: Delta_G Could you please show me in a schematic what you mean?

Comment: chrisl what type of resistor would you recommend me to use?

Comment: I think those modules already have pull-up resistors on them, so pull-ups aren't needed. Connect the SDA and SCL pins directly to the Arduino pins. Also check continuity on your solder connections, because they look a bit crumby. Try holding you iron on the solder connection a bit longer. That is. Put the iron on the connection, trying to touch both the pad and the wire. Add a bit of solder. Keep the iron in the same position for a second or two, to make the solder flow. Then remove the iron.

Comment: @peterk Most likely the resistors aren't necessary, though I always add one 4.7kOhm standard  resistor (0.25W) as pullup resistor on each line, just to be sure

Answer (score 1):

From what I am reading it is not properly connected.  You are getting what I would expect. ACL of the device goes directly to A5 and a pull up resistor to +5. Same thing with SCL, connected directly, both need pull ups. You did not state what it is connected to. If there is nothing connected you will get nothing. Also the old wire library did not support timeout so you could hang indefinitely.

Comment: As I said, I have two 4.7K ohm resistors, one with sda and one with scl. Both are connected with resistors(none directly connected).

Comment: As Delta_G asked, how did you connect the resistors? They should not be in line with the SCL and SDA signals. Could you show a (simple) schematic of how you built it?

Comment: Ok I just added a picture of how I wired everything hope it helps!

Comment: As stated earlier the resistors need to be pull ups, not in series as your photo shows. Also you need to clean up the solder splatter and flux, that could also cause shorts. Isopropyl alcohol 90% works great. I would suggest you get a temperature controlled soldering iron between 40 and 50 watts max,